# rsync folder from local system to server does not work

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to copy my webfolder 'depot' from my local machine to my server on Digital Ocean.

For that I run this command in the terminal:

```
rsync -anv ./Sites/depot root@my-server-ip:/sites
```

But when I ssh into my server and cd into the sites folder, the 'depot' folder is not there.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the `-n` flag, which results in a "dry run" (you get to see which files would be copied/deleted without actually doing any damage).

To do the actual copy you need to omit the `-n` flag:

```
rsync -av ./Sites/depot root@my-server-ip:/sites/depot
```

Also be careful about how you specify paths for rsync - normally you need a trailing `/`:

```
rsync -av ./Sites/depot/ root@my-server-ip:/sites/depot/
```

otherwise you can end up with copies of directories inside of directories (e.g. `sites/depot/depot`).

See [man rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) for full details.

Comment: thanks Paul R, it tried: rsync -an ./Sites/depot/ root@95.85.5.6:/sites/depot , but nothing seems to be copied. I'am working on a Mac, could that be the problem. However, yesterday I successfully rsynced a folder from my local machine to the remote server

Comment: You got rid of the wrong flag - you need `rsync -av` - see above. And yes, this works on Mac OS X.

Comment: phew, after several trail and errors, I got it right, seems like adding 'root' to my path did the trick: rsync -av ./Sites/depot root@my-server-ip:/root/sites . Thanks for your help Paul.